# Rectangle Borders on SSRS 2005

Tags: border, reportingservices-2005

I'm developing a report on SSRS 2005, and I need to set borders to my rectangles. A baby can do this on SSRS 2008, but in 2005 looks like isn't possible.

I tried to look at the Rectangle Properties dialog box but there's nothing about borders. And I also tried to use the tags:

```
<Style>
  <Border>
    <Style>Solid</Style>
  </Border>
</Style>
```

But didn't work.

So, is possible to show borders on the SSRS 2005 element "Rectangle"?

I know that my question isn't one of the bests, but I didn't find in nowhere a direct and clear answer for it.

I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said, my question wasn't a smart one. Well, on the Rectangle Properties Dialog Box there isn't the borders option, but there is in the Properties Window of Visual Studio.

There are a few options to set to your rectangle borders on the Properties Window, so all you need to do is change them in accord to your needs.